# Installing binaries for older MacOS versions with Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm building my open-source game for MacOS in AppVeyor CI (which uses Catalina). I'm installing compiler and dependencies with brew and package it in .app format, and everything seems to work fine, except that when trying to launch resulting application in older MacOS versions (I only have High Sierra available for experimentation) I'm getting errors about newer MacOS version. I suppose if I can force Homebrew to install binaries for older MacOS versions, this would fix the problem, but how exactly can I do that?

I'm aware there's ability to build software from sources in brew, but I don't want to go that route considering I want my CI to be fast.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I'm trying to fix the following error: "You can't use this version of the application MyCoolGame with this version of macOS. You have macOS 10.13.6. The application requires macOS 10.15 or later."

Comment: [Installing a specific version of a homebrew package](http://effectif.com/mac-os-x/installing-specific-version-of-homebrew-formula) or check this [stack-overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763)

Comment: @Akbar30bill the problem is not in the package version, but in the version of MacOS for which the package is built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since time immemorial<sup>†</sup>, there have been two package managers for Macintosh computers: Homebrew and MacPorts. These projects are different in a variety of ways that some folks care about very deeply, and lots of people have opinions about which package manager is better. Once they all get tired of arguing, however, they usually acknowledge that Homebrew and MacPorts do basically the same thing, and return to more important topics like why tabs are better than spaces.

There is one particular difference between Homebrew and MacPorts which may interest you:

**Homebrew** supports the three most recent versions of macOS, which as of this writing is Monterrey, Ventura, and Big Sur. Homebrew can sometimes be installed on older operating systems too, but Homebrew's developers make zero effort to support these systems. The result is lots of breakage.

**MacPorts** also supports the three most recent versions of macOS. However, it also supports older versions of macOS on a "best-effort" basis. Notably, "best-effort" in this context is a term used to mean "a lot of f*cking effort." MacPorts actively maintains bespoke patches, hardware buildbots, and compatibility libraries for every version of macOS going back to OS X Tiger. (OS X Tiger, for those who don't know, is an operating system released in 2005. And 2005, for those who don't know, is a long forgotten age when phones were actually used to make phone calls, Zoom was just a TV series on PBS Kids, and Mug Cake hadn't been invented yet).

You stand at a crossroads. You have two choices. Do you:

- Continue using Homebrew, with full knowledge that most packages will be broken and anything that is not broken will likely become broken in due course and at the least opportune time.
- Use MacPorts, which actively supports your operating system and will continue to do so for the foreseeable future.

Choose wisely.

---

<sup>† aka the year of our lord 2009. That's basically the same thing, right?</sup>

Comment: Using MacPorts surely will solve my trouble. Thank you so much for detailed and interesting answer!

Comment: "there have been two package managers for Macintosh computers" -

All the people using Fink just cried out.

Comment: Looking at the fink page they at least acknowledge the existence of older versions, but I suspect while the package manager itself may run they don't go to the efforts that macports does in ensuring the packages are patched to run on older versions.

You can use homebrew if you really want to, but you'll have to do the same patching that macports does yourself.